# Retrieving firebase data to android

Tags: android, firebase, raspberry-pi, firebase-realtime-database

i try to make android app by retrieve temperature and hum data from firebase

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez1e5.jpg)

how to show the data to textview android?
and how to show the latest inserted data from firebase.
thanks

**UPDATE**

i try this 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6gWh.png)

can you give me an example to show the data to android please?
thanks for your help

Comment: [this official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data) is what you need to read

Comment: As @Wilik mentioned, in the official firebase quickstart guide is everything covered.

You have to create data object, representing your data structure, so for your needs, you need to create class Measurement with three attributes, empty constructor, and getters.

It is really ease, in case you will need some more help, edit your question since you cant comment.

Comment: @PepaKorbel i tried create data object,and show no setter/field

Comment: thank you for your help,it works :)

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working. For a next question, please don't post pictures of code or JSON. Instead post the actual code and JSON, so that we can copy/paste it to test your problem or use it in our answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is a ValueEventListener. In the fragment/activity that displays your TextView, you can add a ValueEventListener to a firebase reference like this:

```
    // Get reference to firebase location where the data is stored
    final Firebase databaseRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

    databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"ValueEventListener:onDataChange: " + "Data has changed");
            // Get data
            String temperatureData = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            // Update UI elements here...

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"ValueEventListener:onCancelled: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Whenever the data at the specified location changes, the onDataChange() callback is triggered, so the UI is always up-to-date. Very powerful.

As someone new to Firebase myself, I can recommend this Udacity course : https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009